# How to simulate cosmos db fail over for testing & development?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Thought of enabling geo redundancy for existing Azure Cosmos DB account? But how to simulate the failover   to do testing & development?

How importance is to consider, the data consistency after enabling  geo redundancy?

What would be general recommendation & guideline/ principles to follow before the deciding required data consistency level?

Any code change required to consider the geo redundancy or to consider data consistency? we are using cosmosdb-sqlapi.

Answer (score 0):

**Manual Failover**

First Azure Cosmos account must be configured for manual failover for this operation to succeed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-database-account#set-failover-priorities-for-your-azure-cosmos-account

The process for performing a manual failover involves changing the account's write region (failover priority = 0) to another region configured for the account.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-database-account#manual-failover

**Consistency**

Azure Cosmos DB offers five well-defined levels. From strongest to weakest, the levels are:

- Strong
- Bounded staleness
- Session
- Consistent prefix
- Eventual

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels#consistency-levels-and-throughput

**CosmosDB Geo Redundancy in application**

You should consider multiple points prior to implement the geo redundancy.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/high-availability#building-highly-available-applications